# How to configure user and password for neo4j cluster without REST API

Tags: neo4j, authorization

The version I use is neo4j-enterprise-2.2.0-M02

My question is :
How can I configure a user (like add a new user, change the password ,etc) in backend or browser, instead of REST API? Can I do it via neo4j-shell? imagine that I am a DBA, it is not very convenient to do this by REST API.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should mark one of the answers below in order to close the question.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use the browser instead of the API. Just go to `http://localhost:7474` (or whatever IP to which the web console is bound) and you will be prompted to change the password. Once authenticated, use the command `:server change-password` to change the password again.

It is not yet possible to create multiple user accounts within the system.

You can use the command `:help server` to see available authentication commands.

Comment: Thanks @subvertallchirs: Yes but I can only change password at the very first time(change from default noe4j/noe4j to new password) ,and then I cannot find where should I change it, right?

Comment: @subvertallchris what happens if you forgot your password?

Comment: @NumenorForLife that would be a separate question, but the answer is here for amyone looking http://boopathi.me/blog/reset-neo4j-graph-database-password/

Comment: what are the command `:something` called? I failed to locate it in [The Neo4j Cypher Manual v4.3](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/ "The Neo4j Cypher Manual v4.3 - Neo4j Cypher Manual")

Answer (score 57):

Although still utilizing the REST API, I'll throw the cURL option out there to anyone who doesn't have access to a web browser (AWS instance, for example):

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"password":"WHATEVER THE PASSWORD IS"}' -u neo4j:neo4j http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password
```

Comment: Now that's what I'm talking about. You can do this from an `ssh` terminal!

Comment: This is the actual answer :)

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to modify the auth file directly and restart neo. Doing this, you can even change the username!

Run

> find / -name dbms

For me this gave one hit:

> /var/lib/neo4j/data/dbms/auth

Save this code as build_auth_string.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEFAULT_IFS="$IFS"
SALT_LEN=32

# either read from stdin or use the argument
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  read INPUT
else
  INPUT="$1"
fi

if [ -z "$INPUT" ]; then
 echo "correct format <uname:pass>"
 exit
fi

IFS=':'
read -a UNAME_PASS <<< "$INPUT"

UNAME="${UNAME_PASS[0]}"
PASS="${UNAME_PASS[1]}"

# representing the password in hex format like \xAB\x0C etc
# HEX_PASS=$(echo -n $PASS | xxd -p | awk '{print toupper($1);}' | sed -r 's/(.{2})/\\x\1/g')
HEX_PASS=$(echo -n $PASS | hexdump -v -e '"\\\x" 1/1 "%02X"')
# echo $HEX_PASS


# create the salt and store it in hex format
SALT=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-f0-9' | fold -w $SALT_LEN | head -n 1)
# SALT="28FD26AD92D6D2D8820E969F3F3732B4"
HEX_SALT=$(echo -n $SALT | sed -r 's/(.{2})/\\x\1/g')


# calculate the sha256 sum of the salt and password value
# need to split the output because the output ends with a hyphen
IFS=' '
read -a PASSWORD_HASH_ARRAY <<< $(printf $HEX_SALT$HEX_PASS | sha256sum)
PASSWORD_HASH="${PASSWORD_HASH_ARRAY[0]}"

# echo "$UNAME;$PASS;$SALT"
# echo "$PASSWORD_HASH"

# and print out the auth string
COMBINED=$(echo -n "$PASSWORD_HASH,$SALT" | awk '{print toupper($1);}')
echo "$UNAME:SHA-256,$COMBINED:"

IFS="$DEFAULT_IFS"
```

The code for the above came from https://github.com/artsince/docker-neo4j-auth/blob/master/build_auth_string.sh - im posting it here just encase..

And then just run the above script like

> build_auth_string.sh myUsername:myP@ssw0rd

Copy/paste that into your auth file replacing whatever was there before, and restart neo4j :)

Answer (score 5):

A fresh install of Neo4j 2.2.x has a user 'neo4j', with an initial password 'neo4j'.  You are required to change the password before you can do anything.

It's easy to do this from the command line, by calling [httpie](http://httpie.org) to interact with the REST API.  For example, to set a new password of 'foobar', run this command:

```
http -a neo4j:neo4j POST http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password password=foobar
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reset the password and you dont know the old password :
then for Windows user 
go to this path:

> C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\dbms

and delete that **auth** file. 
Restart the neo4j they will again ask to set the username and password!!
by default 
username:neo4j
password:neo4j

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible to configure authorization using `neo4j-shell`. As you've mentioned the REST API is the way to go. Using a convenient REST client this is very easy.

My tools of choice is either [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) (a plugin for chrome browser) or [httpie](http://httpie.org) for the command line. E.g. with httpie changing the password for a user is as simple as:

```
 http localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password password=neo4j new_password=mypass
```

Be aware that password (and other authorization settings) are not automatically distributed in a cluster, see the [manual how to copy over settings between instances](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0-M02/rest-api-security.html#rest-api-security-copy-config).

Comment: OK I see, Thank you Stefan, again!

Comment: Please be aware that 2.2.0-M02 is a milestone release, intended for testing out some of the features and getting feedback. The way auth works may change before the 2.2.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac users, version 2.3.1 of Neo4J, best way to reset credentials is to remove the file with credential information and start the service again.

Steps to follow

1. Find where the file that contains credentials is located from the browser console (localhost:7474). Go to Star (Favourites)->System->Server configuration
2. Search for **dbms.security.auth_store.location** property to see where it points to. In my case it was **/Users/felipe/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/./dbms/auth**
3. Delete that file.
4. Start the service again and go to the console again (localhost:7474).

By default you will be asked to set the password for the user neo4j.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on felipe's response (since I do not have enough rep points to comment):
I stopped the server, I deleted the auth files in BOTH:

- DBROOT\data\auth
- DBROOT\dbms\auth

Restarted the server, and connected to it via the localhost:7474, used the default username/password (neo4j/neo4j) and then it prompted me for a new password.

Answer (score 0):

On Neo4j 4.0+, you can run:

```
$ cypher-shell
```

If it's the first time you connect, you can enter `neo4j` as user and password and you will be prompted to set a new password.

If you want to change the password afterwards, you can write in the Cypher shell:

```
:server change-password
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, I'm using neo4jDesktop for WIndows. As other answers suggest, I tried `:server change-password` command, but it didn't work.

`:server change-password` prompts me for existing password and new password. I don't know the existing password, I thought it would be the default `neo4j`, but that value didn't work (does anyone know why?<sup>1</sup>)

I was able to use the Neo4J browser (in which I was already authenticated?) and run the below `ALTER USER` command. Note it **does not ask for my current password.** (It will error if you provide **a new password that is <8 characters long**). This command is described on the neo4j website for [password recovery for admins](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/password-and-user-recovery/#password-recovery-for-admin)

```
ALTER USER neo4j SET PASSWORD 'neo4j-password'
```

Note I did **not** disable authentication in order to run the above command, as suggested on the neo4j site (which they recommend you undo afterwards, see "post-recovery")

I know this answer is many years late, but I don't see another answer like it; I'm posting this here in case it helps other people like me, (i.e. if you don't know the current password)

<sup>1</sup> Why was my default password `neo4j` not working? Maybe I missed the step in Neo4j Desktop installation which prompts me to choose a new/non-default password?

[image: screenshot of neo4j browser, :server change-password command did not work because I didn't get existing password correct. ALTER USER command works, it does not ask me for existing password]