# Neo4j create new admin user from console

Tags: neo4j

Is there any way to add neo4j admin user from console?
I found how to change default password for native user ***neo4j*** https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/set-initial-password/ but didn't found how to add new admin user.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible with the `neo4j-admin` tool, but directly with the `cypher-shell` by running those queries (so you need to have a running database):

```
CALL dbms.security.createUser('root', 'password');
CALL dbms.security.addRoleToUser('admin', 'root');
```

You will find the description of all security's procedures here : https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/authentication-authorization/native-user-role-management/procedures/

Comment: can I create user before starting neo4j?

Comment: It's not possible for the moment with a built-in tool, but you can manually edit files  `auth` and `roles` in the folder `data/dbms`

Answer (score 0):

Since it was needed to set credentials before neo4j start I manually generated login and password using script from this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645951/how-to-configure-user-and-password-for-neo4j-cluster-without-rest-api#answer-31394804) and inserted them to neo4j auth file.